# Migrating Hive timestamp column to Bigquery timestamp/datetime column

Tags: datetime, google-bigquery, hive, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

We are working on migrating Hive table from on-premise to GCP Bigquery.
We have a few timestamp columns in Hive table which stores the timestamp in 'Europe/London' timezone.
These Hive timestamp columns needs to be migrated to Bigquery table columns.
Note - Our Bigquery tables are not partitioned on these timestamp columns.
Example Hive timestamp column value - "2023-07-20T12:20:50"    (this is in 'Europe/London' timezone)

We are facing below challenges while doing migration -

- As Bigquery only stores timestamp in UTC format("2023-07-20T11:20:50 UTC"), we are not able to store the timestamp in 'Europe/London' timezone in Bigquery.
- We did think about using Bigquery DATETIME column type to store timestamp in 'Europe/London' timezone, but the problem here is ,Spark doesn't support writing to DATETIME column in Bigquery yet.

The only solution we can think of is to use STRING type column to store timestamp in 'Europe/London' timezone in Bigquery.

If anyone has ever encountered a similar use case, would like to hear suggestions.

- Can we use STRING type column to store timestamp values('Europe/London' timezone) in Bigquery ??? Will it be a good idea to use STRING type column???
- Any other suggestions ???